# Where and How to wrap params before changeset validation?

Tags: postgis, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Next difficulty after [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870732/how-to-use-geo-library-to-create-valid-ecto-model-changeset/33870807?noredirect=1#comment55549550_33870807), I'm trying to pass into changeset coordinates wrapped by `%Geo.Point` function, in `Map.put` coordinates key stay immutable, but target question is How and where should coordinates be wrapped? Can I do this somewhere inside pattern maching or maybe better before pass changeset in controller or in changeset method in model?

```
def create(conn, %{"notify" => %{"coordinates" => %{"latitude" => latitude, "longitude" => longitude}} = notify_params}) do
  geo = %Geo.Point{coordinates: {latitude, longitude}}
  Map.put(notify_params, :coordinates, geo ) # coordinates are immutable
  changeset = Notify.changeset(%Notify{}, notify_params)
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Map.put(notify_params, :coordinates, geo)` will work, however you are not binding the value.

This will rebind the `notify_params` variable with your new value. Please note that  you should use `"coordinates"` instead of `:coordinates` as the params use strings as keys.

```
notify_params = Map.put(notify_params, "coordinates", geo)
```

There is another (preferred) syntax for map updates that will error if the key does not exist.

```
notify_params = %{notify_params | "coordinates" => geo}
```